# Transfer videos over Wifi to NAS

Tags: ios, photos.app, nas, files.app

Today on my Android phone, I take videos of my kids, 5-10GB weekly, and then move them with xPlore application to the NAS (synology) over the 5G Wifi internal network.

I have a new iPhone XR iOS 14.6 and I would like to do the same, move from the iPhone the movies that I make to the NAS without going over the Internet.

The way I'm doing it right now:

1. I go to the Photos app
2. I select the video in question, I click on the Share button, I choose to copy on my iPhone
3. I go to the Files app and from there transfer the video to the NAS
4. Go back to the Photos app and delete the video
5. Go back to the Files app and delete the video

How can I minimize/simplify the number of steps done above (these are 40 steps for 8 videos)?

I do not need a real time solution, I can move my videos once a week/month.

PS: I understand that it could be done via my Windows PC, to install iTunes, but that is more complicated than via the steps that I described above. I do not have any MAC at home.

Answer (score -1):

The top result from google for, "auto backup photos to NAS ios" is https://www.photosync-app.com/home.html and it seems to accomplish what you want.