# Select files from the "Photos" app on iOS

Tags: ios, photos, file-sharing, file-transfer

How can I select files from the "Photos" directly, without first manually copying from the "Photos" app to the "Files" app?

Currently, in order to send the original, unmodified, and uncompressed photos and videos using messaging apps (such as WhatsApp and Telegram), I have to first open the "Photos" app and transfer the media I want to the "Files" app, specifically internal iPhone files, so that they would show up in the messaging apps' file picker.

I find this process extremely frustrating and inefficient, and I believe this could wear the NAND flash on the iPhone when done repeatedly.

Some other user also has [this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424750/transfer-videos-over-wifi-to-nas), but sadly no one helped them either.

Is there a method or feature that I am unaware of that allows me to select and send the files as documents without compression directly from the Photos app? On Android, there is no unnecessary distinction between regular files and other media, so any app can pick files from any place on the device.

Please note that I need to send the files without making use of iCloud Drive, in other word, I don't want to send iCloud shared links to the recipient, but rather the original files.

Additionally, using the lightning to USB-C cable is inconvenient for these reasons:

1. USB 2.0 is rather slow
2. MTP protocol is broken when dealing with folders with many files
3. Apple wants to automatically lower the quality of HEIC files when transferring using USB
4. I shouldn't need to use a computer to copy files from the iPhone

Comment: Why can‘t you use the Photo picker in WhatsApp directly?

Comment: Also, at the beginning you talk about photo sharing via messenger apps, at the end about USB transfers. How does this fit together?